# OWL reasoning from command line with minimal dependencies

Tags: owl, protege, owl-api, reasoning, owlready

I have an OWL file in rdf/xml syntax which contains an asserted ontology. I want to apply an OWL DL reasoner to derive additional axioms. I know I could open the file in protegé and apply the reasoner there. However I look for a command line solution because I want to automate that process in a script.

I am aware that [owlready2](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) comes with reasoners Pellet and Hermite included as a binary file (`.jar`) but they seem quite outdated ([see e.g. this repo](https://github.com/stardog-union/pellet)), as Pellet 3.0 has become closed source.

I tried to install https://github.com/Galigator/openllet but failed to build it on my machine.

Is there any (preferable FLOSS-licenced) OWL DL reasoner available which can be easily installed and applied via command line?

Comment: Either an older Pellet or HermiT distribution (why not just use those?) or build the Pellet for `openllet` - build works for me, you need Java 17 or you change the version in the `pom.xml` file for the enforcer and the compiler plugins.

Comment: But I doubt you'll find something to compute all inferences in the CLIas this is basically just some utility in the OWL API dubbed `XXXAxiomGenerator` contained in this Java package: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/tree/version5/api/src/main/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/util - the easiest thing would be to implement it by yourself maybe? It's just a plain Maven project with a single class. Or maybe you can find a project with CLI as the `InferredOntologyGenerator` class seems to be used in many projects: https://www.javatips.net/api/org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.inferredontologygenerator

Comment: just copy and paste the `main` method from one of those implementation and adapt it as the used axiom generators vary as you can see - and maybe you want to get all or just some specific axiom types.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the encouragement in the question's comments I managed to build openllet. Here I document the steps:

- Install up-to-date java (see e.g. here https://techviewleo.com/how-to-install-temurin-openjdk-on-debian/)
- Install up-to-date maven (see https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)
- Clone https://github.com/Galigator/openllet/
- Run `mvn package` in the project root

  - Note: currently some test cases might fail
- Go to `openllet/tools-cli/target/openlletcli/bin/` and run `./openllet classify your-ontology.rdf.xml`

  - Note: `openllet` is a shell script which sets some paths and then executes the appropriate java class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ROBOT](http://robot.obolibrary.org) that is used extensively in the biological ontology community in pipelines. To reason using ELK you can use the following command:

```
robot reason --reasoner ELK \
  --input ribosome.owl \
  --output results/reasoned.owl
```

For more details see [ROBOT docs on reasoning](http://robot.obolibrary.org/reason).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Nice bonus: it also has a python interface. Thus I added the tool to https://github.com/pysemtec/semantic-python-overview.